# How to force Spring Data Jpa to read entity from db tables in all test scenarios?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I want to perform Integration testing of Spring Data Jpa repositories.
For example I have an Entity with `@Column(updatable = false)` and want to make sure it will not be updated if I will try.

What i do is:

```
MyEntity ent = repo.findById(id);
assert ent.getNotUpdatableField == true;
ent.setNotUpdatableField(false);
repo.saveAndFlush(ent);
MyEntity updatedEnt = repo.findById(id);
assert ent.getNotUpdatableField == true;
```

The last assertion fails because of for the second time repository returns literally the same object which was returned for the 1st time and was assigned to `ent` variable.
But the field was not actually updated in database and no exception was raised.

To test what I want to test I found a solution to autowire `EntityManager` and call either `.clear()` or `refresh(ent)` on it after `saveAndFlush(ent)`.
I would like to know if it is possible to force repositories to load data from tables in **all** tests? Manual usage of `@Autowired` `EntityManager` in each scenario is tedious.

Probably I do something wrong at all an there are even better ways to test Spring Data JPA entities.

Comment: assert with one `=`?

Comment: *Manual usage of @Autowired EntityManager in each scenario is tedious*: then why don't you add a clear() method in your base repo class? Or use a base class for your DAO tests? Note that `assert` is a Java keyword, that is usually disabled. Not a way to make a JUnit assertion. Use assertTrue(). There is no way to force every find to go to the database. Even if there was, you would then test with JPA semantics completely different from the ones used in production, making your tests basically useless.

Comment: @JBNizet I actually use Hamcrest assertions usually. Here is just a kind of pseudocode. Btw Intellij Idea runs tests with `-ea` usually :) How else could I check that field was not updated? I use dbSetup, not dbUnit with expected datasets feature :)

Comment: Using clear() and reloading it seems exactly what you should do (although I don't see much value in such a test).

Comment: `findOne` is just a wrapper for [`javax.persistence.EntityManager.find(Class, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#find(java.lang.Class, java.lang.Object)). The JavaDocs for that method clearly state that calling that method will return the entity instance from the (in-memory) persistence context, if the instance is already there.